# Celery and Celerybeat randomly start acting funky

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, cron-task, celerybeat

I am using Celery with my Django app and for the most part, things are running grand. For reference, here is my celerybeat configruation:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'update-every-5-secs': {
        'task': 'app1.tasks.task1',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
        'args': (),
    },
    'archive-request-records-every-hour': {
        'task': 'app0.tasks.archive_requests',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour='*/1'),
        'args': (),
    },
    'push-ios-background-every-5-minutes': {
        'task': 'app0.tasks.push_ios_background',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/5'),
        'args': (),
    },
}
```

I've noticed that every 1-2 days, it will just randomly fall completely out of sync. For example, the last entry that runs every 5 minutes normally runs like so: 1:00, 1:05, 1:10, 1:15, etc.

Here is what it did this morning:
7:30, 7:35, 7:40, *7:46*, 7:50, *8:03, 8:16, 8:32, 8:50, 9:13, 9:21, 9:26, 9:29, 9:32, 9:38, 9:47, 9:59, 10:08, 10:22, 10:24, 10:24, 10:24, 10:24, 10:25, 10:25, 10:25, 10:25, 10:25, 10:25, 10:25, 10:25, 10:25, 10:25, 10:25, 10:26, 10:26*, 10:30, 10:35, 10:40...

It almost looks like it falls way out of sync, attempts to make up for it all of once, and then regains itself. At first I thought it was just a fluke, but it is happening way too frequently. I have mission critical processes on this that need to run on time.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? It seems like people have had tons of success with Celery so I am truly baffled.

Comment: What are you measuring? Is this the time the messages were sent by the beat service, or is it the time the tasks were received by a worker?

Comment: Note that if it's the latter (which I would suspect: beat should not send messages in this order) then you must take queue congestion into account.  Say if beat sent 12 task messages the past hour, but the workers are very busy and the queues are filling up, this will cause problems for your periodic tasks which will eventually start to overlap.  If you have a busy cluster then it can be a good idea to use a dedicated worker just for periodic tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your settings look good.

Could it be that you are measuring when the task is completed, not when it is starting? It could be that your tasks take very long or even fail so they do not get reported.

`crontab` is low level and fairly accurate in my experience, so I'd check your logging tool first.

**Update**

Another debugging solution is to start implementing time limits for tasks to make sure they do not get locked too long. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#time-limits

```
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 300
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 260
```

Comment: The thing is they are all very short tasks. A couple of milliseconds at most. Although you bring up an interesting point, if one task that normally is quick takes awhile, will it throw off all three? I only use one worker.

Comment: Each worker may run multiple processes, not sure what the defaults are, but examples usually suggest multi-processes. If your tasks read from the same DB list for example, they might all get stuck the same way. HTTP communication to Apple push server are often slowing down. I suggest you implement time limits as a start: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#time-limits

Comment: Yeah I was just looking into those. Hopefully time limits will solve the issue. I can just throw those into Django's settings.py file right?

Comment: Yes, that's where you put them! You might want to put low limits if you expect the task to run in a couple of milliseconds: eg. 30sec at most

Comment: Yeah I ended up using 30s for the soft limit and 40s for the hard limit. I'll keep an eye on it to see if it works, thank you!